# Passing data between sibling components react hooks without context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'd like to pass data between two siblings, however, for learning purposes, I don't want to use context. I have SearchBar with Autoselect to search for a city:

**SearchBar.js**

```
export const SearchBar = () => {
  const [city, setCity] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [cityList, setCityList] = useState(null)

  const handleOnSearch = (string, cityList) => {
    if(string.length >= 3) {
      const options = {
        method: `GET`,
      };
      fetch(`/api/cityList?city=${string}`, options)
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.ok){
          return response.json().then(setCityList)
        }
          throw new Error('Api is not available') 
        })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
        setError(error)
      })
      .finally(setLoading(false))
    }
  }

  const allCities = cityList ? cityList : []
  const handleOnSelect = (item) => {
    const city = item?.name
    setCity(city)   
  }

  return(
    <div className="mb-6">
      <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
        Search city
      </label>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-5 gap-4">
        <div className="col-span-3">
          <div className="mt-1">
            <ReactSearchAutocomplete
              id="city"
              name="city"
              type="text"
              items={allCities}
              fuseOptions={{ keys: ["name"] }}
              onSearch={handleOnSearch}
              onSelect={handleOnSelect}
              autoFocus
              autoComplete="off"
              className="py-3 px-4 block w-full shadow-sm focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 border-gray-300 rounded-md"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="col-span-2 mt-1">
          <button className="mt-1 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" type='button' onClick={handleOnSelect}>
            Select City
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

On the same index page I have another component that should take the city from the SearchBar.js and do further operations with it:

**ForecastButtons.js**

```
export const ForecastButtons = () => {
  const [payload, setPayload] = useState(null)
  const fetchCityData = () => {
  
    const options = {
      method: `POST`,
    };
    fetch(`/api/weather?city=${city}`, options)
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.ok){
        return response.json().then(setPayload)
      }
        throw new Error('Api is not available') 
      })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error fetching data: ', error)
      setError(error)
    })
    .finally(setLoading(false))
  }
  
  const location = payload?.location?.name;
  const currentTemp = payload?.current?.temp_c;

  return(
    <div className="sm:col-span-2">
      <p className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Select forecast</p>
        <button onSubmit={fetchCityData} className="mt-1 bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded">
          Today
        </button>
        <p key={city?.location?.id} className='my-5'>
          { location ? `Current weather in ${location} is ${currentTemp} degrees ` : 'Please search for city to see current weather'}
        </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I kinda know how to do this with the context, but I am learning to react now so, I would like to go a more "complex" way of passing data between components, without context.

Comment: try using `useRef` to reference the field of City and then passing it as prop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These component don't (and shouldn't) know anything about each other.  From the perspective of the parent component which uses them, they are "siblings" in the sense that they both exist in the markup next to each other.  But it's not *necessary* that they be siblings like that.  That shouldn't be a requirement for using a component.

If these components need to rely on any kind of external state to be passed to them, then you can [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up) to the parent component.  Basically, instead of trying to get the siblings to *talk to each other*, each one should simply expose as props the information it needs.  Then it's the responsibility of whatever component hosts it to provide that information.

So in this case the containing component would track the state for `city`:

```
const [city, setCity] = useState('');
```

The `SearchBar` component needs both of those things passed to it:

```
<SearchBar city={city} setCity={setCity} />
```

And it would internally use them instead of tracking that state itself:

```
export const SearchBar = ({city, setCity}) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [cityList, setCityList] = useState(null)

  // the rest of the logic is the same...
};
```

And the `ForecastButtons` component just needs to know the `city`:

```
<ForecastButtons city={city} />
```

Which it uses as a prop:

```
export const ForecastButtons = ({city}) => {
  const [payload, setPayload] = useState(null)
  // the rest of the component...
};
```

The idea is that the state is being tracked at the higher level component so it can be shared by the child components.

---

As an app grows, this can of course get fairly complex.  In some codebases which don't use effective state management you might find components passing state values through them from much higher levels, just so lower level components can use that state.  This is the problem `useContext` is meant to solve.  Alternatively, you might use a state management library like `Redux` to manage state globally and each component can read just the state it needs.

But either way, any time two components need to share the same state, that state is refactored out of those components into a higher level (the parent component, a contect, a global state manager) for those components to share.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to move state that allows changing a city to index component that holds `ForceastButtons` and `SearchBar` components.

```
 const [city, setCity] = useState('')
```

Apart from that it is necessary pass down `setCity` method to `SearchBar` and city state to both child components.